# Transform JSX to JS using babel

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, babeljs

I'm new to babel and I'm trying to convert my main.jsx file to main.js. I installed the following babel plugin.

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx
```

Created a file called .babelrc in the application root directory.

```
{
   "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx"]
}
```

My app is using the express server, so on running node app.js I was expecting the babel to transform main.jsx to main.js but nothing happens.
Can any one point out what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Where do you run `babel` command?  Also, the `react` preset is probably a better thing to use in the `.babelrc`.

Answer (score 13):

if you are only using babel to transform jsx to js, this is what you need :

**installation**

- install `babel-cli` as global (optional) `sudo npm install -g babel-cli`
- install `babel-preset-es2015` (optional. if your code using es6 standard) `npm install babel-preset-es2015`
- install `babel-preset-react` (required)

**configuration**

in your root of project, add this file `.babelrc` and write this to it

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

or

```
{
  "presets": ["react"]
}
```

**run**

```
babel source_dir -d target_dir
```

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the instructions at https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx

First, create a new folder, `test`, and from the folder init a new project:

`npm init`

Install babel CLI

`npm install --save-dev babel-cli`

Then install babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx

`npm i babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx`

In the `test` folder create a sample jsx file `index.jsx`

```
var profile = <div>
  <img src="avatar.png" className="profile" />
  <h3>{[user.firstName, user.lastName].join(' ')}</h3>
</div>;
```

And finally, run the transofmation command in you terminal from the `test` folder:

`.\node_modules\.bin\babel --plugins transform-react-jsx index.jsx`

You'll see the output in you terminal window.

Comment: This gives me following error: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined. How can I include this with babel?

Answer (score 1):

As of **2023** if you are using babel to transform `jsx` to `js`, this is what you  will need to do:

### Install Packages

Install the following globally on your machine:

```bash
npm install -g @babel/cli
npm install -g @babel/core
npm install -g @babel/preset-react
```

or install the following as a project dependency (my personal preference):

```bash
npm install --save-dev @babel/cli
npm install --save-dev @babel/core
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react
```

### Create Configuration File

Create a `.babelrc` config file at the root of your project with the following setting as a bare minimum:

```json
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

You should review the [babel docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/) if you have a more complicated use case and determine what additional settings you may need to add. You can find the settings for compiling `jsx` to `js` on the [@babel/preset-react page](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react).

### Compile

You can compile any `jsx` file into `js` by running the following command in your terminal:

```bash
npx babel [jsx-file-here.jsx] -d [output-directory]
```

If your `jsx` file imports anything please keep the following in mind:

1. This will not import any imported code. You will need to also compile any files that are imported. You can then use your code as a browser module: see next 2 points.
2. JS imports are [widely supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=import) now ([see also](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)) but you will need to add `type="module"` to the script tag in your HTML.
3. Remember you must include the file extension `.js` in your import statements still! No browser will intuptret import Foo from './bar' as `import Foo from './bar.js`.
4. If you do not want to do the previous you can use something like [rollup.js](https://rollupjs.org/) to bundle all the files into a single script.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure webpack and use `babel` as a loader to `transpile` your jsx

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports ={

    context: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
    devtool: "inline-sourcemap",
    entry: "./main.js",
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015','stage-0'],

                }
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname+ "/src",
        filename: "client.min.js"
    }
}
```

[**Tutorials**](https://www.codementor.io/tamizhvendan/beginner-guide-setup-reactjs-environment-npm-babel-6-webpack-du107r9zr)