# Importing React Component with JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jsx, babeljs

There was a problem with importing react component with JXS. Components are imported from library (used like a SDK).

/sdk/dist/js/app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

 export default class Test extends Component {
    render() {
       return <div>Hello</div>;
    }
 }
```

There is a project where this SDK is used, there is webpack / babel that already does a build, the file with import of this component looks like this:

app/js/index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Test from 'sdk/dist/js/App';
```

Result:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

BUT!
Everything will work if:

1. We remove JSX from this component

app/js/index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Test extends Component {
    render() {
        return React.createElement(
            "div",
            null,
            "Hello"
        );
    }
}
```

2. Remove import and insert component directly.

app/js/index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Test extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div>Hello</div>;
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

The problem is that it needs to work through import. I suggest that the problem is that the webpack does not transpose the imported file - and reads it as is ...

webpack:

```
{
      entry: './app/js/index.js',
      output: {
        path: resolve(__dirname, plConfig.paths.public.root),
        filename: "[name].js"
      },

      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                  cacheDirectory: true
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you need to transform the jsx into js in your babel config. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111618/transform-jsx-to-js-using-babel

Comment: If u have any stylesheets anywhere... You'll need a css-loader also setup in ur Webpack...

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a babel plugin to transform jsx...

`@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx`

Install 
`npm i -D @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx`

Use in .babelrc

```
{
    presets: [ ... ],
    plugins: [ "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx", ...other plugins ]
}
```

**EDIT**:

You also need to add a babel rule for **jsx**...
In your webpack module rules...

Change `test: /\.js$/` to `test: /\.jsx?$/`

Comment: I have installed and added this plugin in my babelrc, but still gives an error.. "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type."

Comment: In your webpack module rules, change `test: /\.js$/` to test: `/\.jsx?$/`

Comment: Should i change the file index.js to index.jsx?

Comment: There's no need.. the regex. `/\.jsx?$/` targets both `js` and `jsx`....

Comment: I've noticed that some IDEs provide additional coding assistance (eg. Emmet support) when the file type is jsx though...

Comment: @stoner Did it fix the issue...??

Comment: I  will check and answer tomorrow, because i will be at computer only tomorrow

Comment: The error seems to be originating from a Header component though...

Comment: Could u send screenshots of that as well...??

Comment: Trivial question but did u restart ur webpack server after the change...??

Comment: yep, i restarted webpack server, component will be renamed to Test, same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203728/discussion-between-stoner-and-kwame-opare-asiedu).