# React component not rendering with using modular JS setup

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As part of learning React, I am trying to write my first custom component. However, I am having issues rendering the component. Here is the simple code I have:

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 
    <title>React</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.jss

```js
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>Fun Facts about React</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Was first released in 2013.</li>
            <li>Was originally created by Jordan Walke.</li>
            <li>Has well over 100K stars on GitHub.</li>
            <li>Is maintained by Facebook.</li>
            <li>Powers thousands of enterprise apps, including mobile apps.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />);
```

The output that I see in the browser:

[image: index.html]

This setup is using React and React-DOM 18.2.0 (installed via npm).

I am having a hard time debugging why my component is not rendered.
My code seems to align with the [React docs](https://react.dev/learn/add-react-to-an-existing-project#using-react-for-a-part-of-your-existing-page).

What am I doing wrong here?
Any suggestions on how should I procced and get this working?

Comment: _"My code seems to align with the React docs."_: Not quite. The docs don't mention JSX at that point (which is what you've created in that component) so it might be that you haven't set up any build process to deal with that. You might consider a dev/build tool like [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) to deal with all of that for you. (I've just tested your code with Vite and it works without issue).

Comment: The alternative is to do the [transpilation yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111618/transform-jsx-to-js-using-babel).