# NextJS Web Component <script>

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Hi I have a NextJS app where I create chatbots.

I need to be able to integrate a floating button on other people's web pages so that their clients can access the chat from the button, but I can't find a way to export a NextJS component and be able to integrate it in

Is there any way to do this?

I'm not interested in the iframe because I need it to be a button that can be placed at the bottom right.

Example:

```
    <script>
window.embeddedChatbotConfig = {
chatbotId: "fUYYCegK9QYOtoGJ25Dv1",
domain: "www.chatbase.co"
}
</script>
<script
src="https://www.chatbase.co/embed.min.js"
chatbotId=""
domain="www.chatbase.co"
defer>
</script>
```

Is there a library that allows you to do this? Is there any tutorial on this that you recommend? I've looked for tutorials but I can't find any that work.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transform JSX to JS using babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111618/transform-jsx-to-js-using-babel)

Comment: @ChrisHamilton tu make an external web component, do I have to convert my jsx to js? And also how can I make it public from my nextjs project? Thanks

Comment: @ChrisHamilton If I make a js file in the public folder, can I then import it to other web pages?

Comment: Jsx is not consumable by the browser, it needs to be compiled by a framework like React. If you want to have your button be consumable via a script tag then you need to compile it first.
If you just want to be able to import the jsx into another project that supports jsx, you can make a node module and upload it to the npm registry. You can then add it as a dependency of other projects via package.json. You should be able to find many examples of premade React components on the npm registry.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton Would you recommend using "react to web component"? In this example "https://www.chatbase.co/embed.min.js" they have the embed within their project, they also use NextJS... maybe they added the js file in th public folder. Thanks!!!